# How can I show subdomain data in GA4?

Tags: google-analytics-4, gtag.js

I am attempting to view subdomain data in GA4. My client has a main site, with several additional subdomains all using the same gtag.js tag (I confirmed that they are all using the same gtag). When I view data in Google Analytics, I'm not seeing the subdomain URLs.

I have attempted the following to access the data:

- I set up the primary domain as an "Unwanted Referral", though I was not seeing the subdomains listed when viewing Reports > Acquisition > Traffic Acquisition > Type Referral in the local search > Switch Session Default Channel Group to Session source/medium).
- I set up a segment: (Sessions > Hostname > subdomain url) but am not seeing the subdomains listed in the auto-populate dropdown. When I enter the subdomain manually, no data is shown.
- The subdomains are showing as indexed in Google Search Console.
- I confirmed that the site is using the correct configuration of Google's Global Site Tag (gtag.js). Specifically, the default setting of the cookie domain parameter is set to 'auto'.

I would expect to see subdomain data in Google Analytics, but am not getting anything. Would it be better to set unique accounts for each subdomain?

Answer (score 0):

Cookie domain shouldn't matter here. GSC most definitely does not matter. Referral traffic shouldn't matter either. The start of your debugging should really be looking at all the distinct values of the hostname dimension.

If you don't see your hostname there, then the next step is verifying proper tracking on the missing hostname. Go there, pay attention to the `tid` value in the network request to google's `collect` endpoint. The tid should be exactly the same as the tid of the main site, unless you're using a different source for the subdomain, but it's unlikely.

Wrong tid is the most probable issue. If it's exactly the same, then check the `dl` field in the network request. Make sure it contains correct subdomain.

The next step I would take is checking the [Filters](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/10108813?hl=en) of the property you're looking at. Make sure you're not filtering your traffic out.

If these don't help and you still have the issue, make the screenshot of your explorer where you pull out the hostname dimension by hit and show the screenshot of the ga4 event that you believe should be displayed there.

Comment: Thanks @BNazaruk. I checked my hostname dimension (Reports > Engagement > Pages and screens > added the Hostname dimension) and found only my primary domain. None of the subdomains are displaying. I inspected the primary domain in Dev Tools and found a GET request from Google Tag Manager and two POST requests to Google Analytics containing my Measurement ID. When inspecting the subdomains, however, I'm only seeing a single GET request from Google Tag Manager. I'm thinking we should be seeing the POST on the subdomains as well. Any idea why that would be missing?

Comment: yes, if you don't see POSTs to `collect` endpoint, that means no tracking is happening. Install the plugin from adswerve to see actual events in the console rather than network. Makes it much easier. Use it to confirm that nothing fires on your subdomains. Once you confirm that, feel free to make a new question about tags not firing on subdomains if you can't figure it out on your own. Make sure to add screenshots of your GTM preview and pageview trigger config.